# How to update individual dictionaries in the column of the pandas dataframe based upon some conditions using np.where/np.select?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe df like below

```
    id Surname   DOB                X1   Y1     TRACEID
0   1   Garud   2019-01-01T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}         
1   2   Garud   2019-01-01T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}            
2   3   Garud   2019-01-02T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}            
3   4   Kadam   2019-01-06T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}            
4   5   Kadam   2019-01-03T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}            
5   6   Kadam   2019-01-04T12:10    xxx yyyy    {}
```

TRACEID column contains empty dictionaries:
I want to fill these dictionaries based upon columns X1 & Y1.

- If both X1 & Y1 column values are non null then corresponding TRACEID should be {'X1':'xxx','Y1':'yyyy'}
- If Y1 column value is null then TRACEID would be {'X1':'xxxx'}
- If X1 column value is null then TRACEID would be {'Y1':'yyyy'}

I tried with following

```
list1 = ['X1','Y1']
for col in list1:
    df['TRACEID'] = np.where(df[col]!='',df['TRACEID'].update({col:df[col]}),df['TRACEID'])
```

However this is assigning all None values in the TRACEID column.

I know, I can do it with `df.iterrows()`, but dont want to do it as it's take lot of time to iterate. df has ~100k records. So has to be achieved using `np.select` or `np.where`.

Comment: what happens when both columns are null in the same row?

Comment: This is super easy with `apply()`, would you want this answer?

Comment: @Umar.H - Its not possible in my case. Either of the column will always have value.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh - Yes please, will be helpful.

Comment: `n'p.where` is not an iterator.  The 3 arguments are evaluated in full before being passed to it.   Look at them separately and tell us if the values make sense.  The dicts are separate objects (or maybe the same one) and have to be updated individually.

Comment: Series `update` modifes the series in-place.  Thus it returns `None`, not a series.  While the name is similar, I don't see evidence that it does anything to `dict` elements of the series.  This series `update` is not the same as `dict.update`

Comment: @hpaulj Brilliant, I realized this when eating breakfast. Go to this question found you had already found out. Mine me turn this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative strategy would be producing full `dict`s by `.to_dict()` and clean the dicts up afterwards. This is not meant to be easier than a single step apply, but can provide flexibility for manipulating the output dictionaries.

## Data

```
import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
    id Surname   DOB                X1    Y1     TRACEID
0   1   Garud   2019-01-01T12:10    nan  yyyy    {}         
1   2   Garud   2019-01-01T12:10    xxx   nan    {}            
2   3   Garud   2019-01-02T12:10    nan   nan    {}            
3   4   Kadam   2019-01-06T12:10    xxx  yyyy    {}            
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine='python')
```

## Solution

```
# get the full dict directly
df["TRACEID"] = df[["X1", "Y1"]].to_dict(orient="records")
# clean up the dict
df["TRACEID"] = df["TRACEID"].apply(lambda dic: {k: v for k, v in dic.items() if not pd.isna(v)})
```

## Result

```
print(df)

    id Surname               DOB   X1    Y1                      TRACEID
0 1      Garud  2019-01-01T12:10  NaN  yyyy               {'Y1': 'yyyy'}
1 2      Garud  2019-01-01T12:10  xxx   NaN                {'X1': 'xxx'}
2 3      Garud  2019-01-02T12:10  NaN   NaN                           {}
3 4      Kadam  2019-01-06T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
Any idea why my solution doesn't work ?

list1 = ['X1','Y1']
for col in list1:
    df['TRACEID'] =np.where(df[col]!='',df['TRACEID'].update({col:df[col]}),df['TRACEID'])

Comment: `df[col]!=''` doesn't look right. Did you mean `~df[col].isna()`?

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your `df['TRACEID'].update({col:df[col]})` is that you are misusing [pandas.Series.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) and `dict.update()`. They are two different methods. You can do

```py
# Make sure `TRACEID` column is dict
df['TRACEID'] = [dict() for _ in range(len(df['TRACEID']))]

def update_dict(row):
    # Copy the original dict, since dict.update is inplace,
    # it will affect the original on in `df['TRACEID']`
    copied = row['TRACEID'].copy()
    copied.update({col: df.loc[row.name, col]})
    return copied

for col in list1:
    df['TRACEID'] = np.where(df[col] != '', df.apply(update_dict, axis=1), df['TRACEID'])
```

Also, [pandas.Series.update()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html) modifies Series in place. So you can't do

```py
for col in list1:
    res = []
    for i, v in zip(df.index, df['TRACEID']):
        copied = v.copy()
        copied.update({col: df.loc[i, col]})
        res.append(copied)

    df['TRACEID'] = np.where(df[col]!='', df['TRACEID'].update(pd.Series(res)), df['TRACEID'])
```

You can use `apply()` directly. `axis=1` means [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the function on rows.

```py
def update(row):
    traceid = dict()

    for col in ['X1', 'Y1']:
        if row[col] != '':
            traceid[col] = row[col]

    return traceid


df['TRACEID'] = df.apply(update, axis=1)
```

```
# print(df)

   id Surname               DOB   X1    Y1                      TRACEID
0   1   Garud  2019-01-01T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
1   2   Garud  2019-01-01T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
2   3   Garud  2019-01-02T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
3   4   Kadam  2019-01-06T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
4   5   Kadam  2019-01-03T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
5   6   Kadam  2019-01-04T12:10  xxx  yyyy  {'X1': 'xxx', 'Y1': 'yyyy'}
```

Comment: This works but as I said, for larfe dataframe > 1 lakh rows, this will consume too much of time as it executes line by line. 
Need to use numpy.where or numpy.select to expedite the execution. Any answer using these will be highly appreciated.